# A user vs the user - the 2nd is more common? why?

Tags: word-choice, articles

Why do we use "the" with "user" and not "a", even through we're not talking about a particular user, but about any user? For example:

```
When the user comes to the home page, they should see this link.
```

Comment: Because he's being envisioned as a single, Platonic, ideal user, with a single set of objectives, expectations, and tastes. Which causes no end of troubles, of course.

Comment: @DanBron Is there an English grammar rule saying that we must use "the" for users "being envisioned as a single, Platonic, ideal user, with a single set of objectives, expectations, and tastes"?

Comment: Yes: it's the one you're already familiar with. Such an animal is *necessarily* unique. And unique entities take the definite article. (Also, please be wary of anything someone is trying to sell you as "an English grammar rule"; there's a lot of genuine imitations out there ;)

Comment: @DanBron, As I said, I meant "any user".

Comment: @Dan Bron - you answered this question well, and surely to OP's satisfaction, so you should post as an answer and clear the queue.

Comment: @LittleEva, maybe you should OP whether it's answered well or not?

Comment: I  thought you were all the way over in SE Asia and didn't realize you could overhear us. So what are your thoughts, Alex?

Comment: @LittleEva, am I supposed to laugh?

Comment: Oh Alex, I don't care what you do.

Comment: @LittleEva, you don't have to but you'd better off if you did.

Comment: In a word, why?

Comment: @LittleEva, I've upvoted your comments too.

Comment: @Alex, I don't understand your most recent comment addressing me. Can you elaborate? What are you responding to?

Comment: @DanBron, **Yes: it's the one you're already familiar with. Such an animal is necessarily unique.** - I'm not. I'm talking about any user. "A" user = "one" of, any, whoever it is.

Comment: @Alex I thought I had addressed that with my first comment. You asked why *the user* is more common than *any user*, and I told you why: because people envision the perfect, idealized, user for their application; one whose characteristics, motivations, and expectations are such that *any* change to or variation of them would make him a less perfect, less ideal, less suited user of that application. Which means there can only be one of him: he is THE user. So, while *you* may be talking about *any* user, your interlocutors are clearly not: they're talking about THE (*singularly* ideal) user.

Comment: @Alex And to clarify: when I said "*Yes, it's the one you're already familiar with*", I was responding to your follow-up question "*Is there any any English grammar rule saying..?*". That is, the antecedent and referent of my "*it*" was your "*English grammar rule*", *not* some hypothetical user. The rule in play here is the common rule you're familiar with regrading the definite article: when there's only *one possible entity*, when the referent is *unique*, you use the definite article: *THE Sun*, *THE Earth*, *THE largest diamond*, *THE perfect glass of wine*, *THE (perfect) user*.

Comment: @DanBron, okkkk. You were right. I was ... less right.

Comment: @Alex No problem. If it helps resolve the dissonance for you, rather than think of him as the "Platonic ideal" user, you may prefer to label him the *normative*, *reference*, user.

Comment: @DanBron, but is it wrong to use "a" with user in the same context?

Comment: That's a different question. You could use *a user* as well, but the reason *the* is used is because it makes it clear were talking in the abstract; the reference user *represents* any and all actual, physical users. I'd be more likely to use *a* in an operational context, rather than a design context. That is, when we're closer to concrete than abstract. But use what you want! So long as everyone understands what you're saying, it doesn't matter how you say it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just to close this, let me summarise the above. 'The' is essentially demonstrative in force: it points to our shared mental space. Like any demonstrative 'a' is dropped before it. So 'the user' is 'whichever user we happen to be talking about at the moment' and there is indeed such a user, so 'the' is natural. 'A user' is not wrong in itself, but it lacks the demonstrative force and so is less clear. 
May I take the chance of repeating Dan Bron's excellent comment:  'Also, please be wary of anything someone is trying to sell you as "an English grammar rule"; there's a lot of genuine imitations out there ;)' Right on there, Don!!!